# Parametrized webhooks in Jira

Tags: jenkins, jira, webhooks

What parameters/templates can I pass to a webhook other than `${issue.key}`? I'm trying to pass the value of certain fields as a parameter to the `URL`.

**I'm trying to create a With an `URL` like the following :**

> http://:/jenkins/job/Parameters/buildWithParameters?delay=0sec&PAR1=${issue.key}&PAR2=${something}&PAR3=${something_else}

but until now I've put it to work with `${issue.key}` parameter. Are others parameters valid?

**I'm trying to pass the following parameters in the `webhook`:**

> - Fields Values.
> - Username from the user that trigger the transaction that use this webhook.

The idea is that these parameters are replaced, by information on issue, in order to trigger a Job on Jenkins.

Where can I find documentation/examples about it? The one provided by Atlassian only refers to the `${issue.key}` parameter

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation:
https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/latest/concepts/context-parameters.html

**JIRA supports these context variables:**

- issue.id, issue.key
- project.id, project.key
- version.id
- component.id
- profileUser.name, profileUser.key (this is available on the view user profile page)

**Confluence supports these context variables:**

- content.id, content.version, content.type, content.plugin
- space.id, space.key
- page.id, page.version, page.type DEPRECATED
- agileBoard.id, agileBoard.mode

Comment: Thanks for the response, but if I write a URL with a parameter like this issueid=${issue.id}, jira give me the following error. **Invalid template has been used in the url**. I can only put the webhook working with the issue.key parameter